# Transition to a route after successful save without deleting record

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Ember-1.0.0 and Ember Data 1.0 Beta 2 with Fixture Adapter.

What I'm trying to accomplish is that after I call `save` I'd like to transition to a route if the returned promise is resolved.

In [this jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ulOKuVe/4/) you can click 'New', type in someting then click 'Create'. The transition occurs, therefore the promise from `save` is resolved, but then the new model we created gets deleted due to the `deactivate` hook.

As an aside, having the chrome ember inspector open on the data window is probably helpful.

My implementation is obviously wrong though. How should I go about saving a record, then wait for the promise to resolve before transitioning to a route without deleting the new created record?

Here is the save action:

```
save: function() {
  var self = this;
  self.modelFor('thingsNew').save().then(function() {
    self.transitionTo('things');
  });
}
```

And the deactivate hook:

```
deactivate: function() {
  var model = this.modelFor('thingsNew');
  if(!model.get('isSaving')) {
    model.deleteRecord();
  }
}
```

See the [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ulOKuVe/4/edit) for everything else.

The reason for `deactivate` is so that the model in `thingsNew` gets properly deleted when the user clicks on another link or presses the back button before clicking the create button. For example lets say the user clicks `New` then `Home`. The model would still be around. If the user clicks `New` again, a new model is created. Now we have two new models. If the user clicks `Home` then `New` yet again, now we have three models. If a valid input is entered and the user finally clicks on `Create`, have one new saved model and two new unsaved models still floating around. I don't think there's even a way to access those floating models anymore.

Finally, if I just call the two methods then the model will call `save` then transition without deleting the model, but it will do so regardless whether the promise is resolved or rejected.

```
model.save();
model.transitionTo('things');
```

Just to note this also seems to happen with RESTAdapter. The record is successfully created on the server, but the model still gets deleted in the Ember app during the transition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I now understand better why you want to delete at "deactivate".  I always learned that it is better not to use deactivate (will not fire when switching between for example xxx/edit/1 and xxx/edit/2).

You can better use willTransition.  Here is the code I use:

```
App.AuthorsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.createRecord('author');
  },

  actions: {
    willTransition: function(transition) {
      var model = this.get('currentModel');
      if (model && model.get('isDirty')) {
        if (confirm("You have unsaved changes. Click OK to stay on the current page. Click cancel to discard these changes and move to the requested page.")) {
          //Stay on same page and continue editing
          transition.abort();
        } else {
          //Delete created record
          var author = this.get('currentModel');
          author.deleteRecord();
        }
      } 
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! `willTransition` with `isDirty` definitely takes care of all the problems I've been encountering. That router facelift totally spoils us doesn't it? lol.

Answer (score 0):

Looked into your code.  Why have you implemented a "deleterecord" in the deactivate ?

The deactivate is called at every route change and you have implemented a delete in the deactivate, so it is normal that the record is deleted ...

if(!model.get('isSaving')) means that if you are not in the isSaving state (which only happens during a very short period of time), then delete the record ...

I think you can just delete the complete deactivate block.  And then it will work.

Marc

Comment: I've added some more info and an example of why I implemented `deactivate`. To be honest the reason I thought deactivate was the correct hook for this is because the generated routes in ember-tools does this. But why is it that calling `transitionTo` without waiting for the promise from `save` behaves how I expect it to?